# One hot encoder confusion

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn

This is what I have done. I think there is something going on with One hot encoder.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE


X, y = make_classification(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=10)
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(X)
X = encoder.transform(X)
print X
print X.shape

encoder = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
encoder.fit(X)
X = encoder.transform(X)


print encoder.feature_indices_

estimator = SVR(kernel="linear")
selector = RFE(estimator, 100, step=1)
selector = selector.fit(X, y)
```

After using label encoder on X I got an array of shape (50, 10) (which is obvious). But after doing One hot encoding, the feature indices I get are as follows.

```
[   0  499  987 1487 1968 2459 2957 3401 3886 4379 4868]
```

As far as I know, the maximum range of between 2 indices should be less than or equal to number of rows, isn't it? which is 50. But here I got 500 instead of 50. Have I gotten it wrong about One hot encoding or is there any other issue with One hot encoding function?

(This example is taken only to demonstrate my problem)

Answer (score 1):

The number of rows doesn't matter but rather the range of values across rows within any given column (i.e. feature). When you print X you will see that your values in any given column may span the full range from 1:500.